# How do I find out what credentials I need to run a command?

Tags: graphics, password

Whenever I go to use my computer I always get the message "Your computer is running in low graphics mode".

People have directed me to the terminal to enter a command but I don't know what my credentials are.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal, enter the command :

```
sudo <command>
```

You will be asked for a password, it is the same as your log in password. You will not see anything in the terminal as you type your password. That  is normal behavior, just enter your password and hit enter.

Comment: But how do i know what my username is?

Comment: Nevermind i figured out my username and password but could you explain the command part better? Im new to ubuntu

Comment: Your user name is your login name. If you do not know it, `ls /home` or use the command `id`

Comment: Post the command you want to run when you posted "enter a command "

Answer (score 0):

In Linux (and Unix in general), there is a SuperUser named Root. The SuperUser can do anything and everything, and thus doing daily work as the SuperUser can be dangerous. You could type a command incorrectly and destroy the system. Ideally, you run as a user that has only the privileges needed for the task at hand. In some cases, this is necessarily Root, but most of the time it is a regular user.

By default, the **root** account password is locked in Ubuntu.

There are also **administrator** users and **normal** users

The first account you set up is an **administrator** user, Subsequent users are not if you need to give another user administrator privileges run the the following command in a terminal

```
    sudo adduser <username> sudo
```

where you replace username with the name of the user (without the <>).

The **root** user can run any command without question, which is part of the reason the account is locked by default.  **Administrators** can also run any command but need to ask for special privileges to run restricted commands,  **normal** users can not run restricted commands at all.

As an **administrator** you can run GUI programs such as nautilus (default file manager) with super user powers by pressing ALT+F2 and typing `gksu nautilus` for other programs replace nautilus with the name of the program you want.

For command line programs the syntax is slightly different.  To run a command as a super user type

```
    sudo command
```

replace command with the command you want for example `fdisk -l` does nothing because it's a restricted command but `sudo fdisk -l` lists all the drives your computer can see.

For both sudo and gksu you will be asked to enter your password.

To find out what credentials you have enter `whoami` to get your user name; if it does not say **root** you are not root.  Next enter `id` this lists what groups you belong to if **sudo** is listed you are an administrator, otherwise you are a normal user

There is more information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)